# "stack.cpp not found" prevents debug in VS 2013 express

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I'm a rookie at C in general and VS 2013 also. I am trying to use some C code provided by a vendor in VS 2013 express. It compiles and runs without problem using the command line compiler but I would like to use the IDE.

I started a new project, C++ for console app, and I have pasted the code into the IDE and saved it as xyy.c so that it builds successfully. I thought it would be nice to have it in a GUI, so I duplicated the effort with a Win32 app project. It also builds.

The program's job is to connect to a PCI card that has Plx chip as an interface and program an FPGA. The Win32 program succeeds, even though I can't see any of the info printed by the program. The console program fails and I think it is because it fails to find the driver for the Plx chip. I thought I would get a clue by single stepping through the Win32 program to see which driver was supposed to be found.

However, after the first pass through a while loop, I get a pop up that says "Source Not Found" and "stack.cpp not found". Google wasn't any help to me.

I be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like `stack.cpp` is in some code for which you have a PDB but not the source.  I don't think google will help here as it's likely specific to the vendor.  Look and see what DLL the source code is coming from and see if you can track down the source for that DLL.

Comment: It must be something like that. Strangely, now it goes through that portion but now it wants ullshr.asm (long shift right, probably part of some MS library).

I guess I just have to step-out of these situations. I'm pretty sure my problems are at a higher level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" enabled (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx). So when you are at Stack... and trying to step into, it will actually try, but you don't have the sources for that. There is also a new experience for using the .NET framework reference source that was announced recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I advise at the moment of receiving the information "stack.cpp not found" to look at the stack trace and check if there is something like this: "*RTC*".
If there is, you need to change the flag along the path (for example, set the **Default** or a more convenient configuration for you):

```
Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Basic Runtime Checks
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-160